# what is mean by implement color_content_masks = deepcopy(color_content_masks) in the Torch7 code below?

Tags: lua, deep-learning, torch, style-transfer

```
if is_pooling then
   for k = 1, #color_codes do
     color_content_masks[k] = image.scale(color_content_masks[k], math.ceil(color_content_masks[k]:size(2)/2), math.ceil(color_content_masks[k]:size(1)/2))
     color_style_masks[k]   = image.scale(color_style_masks[k],   math.ceil(color_style_masks[k]:size(2)/2),   math.ceil(color_style_masks[k]:size(1)/2))
   end
elseif is_conv then
   local sap = nn.SpatialAveragePooling(3,3,1,1,1,1):float()
   for k = 1, #color_codes do
      color_content_masks[k] = sap:forward(color_content_masks[k]:repeatTensor(1,1,1))[1]:clone()
      color_style_masks[k]   = sap:forward(color_style_masks[k]:repeatTensor(1,1,1))[1]:clone()
   end
end  
color_content_masks = deepcopy(color_content_masks)
color_style_masks = deepcopy(color_style_masks)
```

The code above is a torch project about deep photo style transfer. You can find the code in https://github.com/luanfujun/deep-photo-styletransfer. The function `deepcopy()` is as below which is the same as recommended in Lua official site.

```
function deepcopy(orig)
    local orig_type = type(orig)
    local copy
    if orig_type == 'table' then
        copy = {}
        for orig_key, orig_value in next, orig, nil do
            copy[deepcopy(orig_key)] = deepcopy(orig_value)
        end
        setmetatable(copy, deepcopy(getmetatable(orig)))
    else -- number, string, boolean, etc
        copy = orig
    end
    return copy
end
```

As you can see, in the `If` statement `color_content_masks` and `color_style_masks` is change directly, so why do we need to implement a deepcopy?

Comment: this is not a code reading service. you should at least provide some own ideas, a direct link to the file and all relevant code should be posted here. if you want to know why someone creates a deep copy of a table you should include the definition and further use of that table. please read [ask]. simple answer: because the programmer wanted to. is it necessary? well remove the deep copy and see if anything changes. maybe there is no reason. not every code you find online is perfect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why to implement x=deepcopy(x) in the Torch7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531880/why-to-implement-x-deepcopyx-in-the-torch7)

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I have to admit it is not good question, and it would be closed.  anyway, deepcopy is actually very nessary here, since we need to inherit the settable after color_content_masks is go forward the net.